# How to hide the parts of page before all of them loads completely

Tags: html, css, lazy-loading

Before my page fully loads, it gets really nasty.

I can solve this by using preloader. But I don't want that.

I see this on many websites. Some parts show certain animation before the page is fully opened. Then, when the parts are fully opened, the page takes the form it needs.

How and which tool can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solution you have to use JS frameworks such Angular, React, or Vue. They use  lifecycle hook. More than likely use a before mounted & mounted lifecycle hook which performs actions until an item is fully loaded, then performs different actions.

For more information have a look:

[ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), [VueJs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html)

Comment: Its not necessary

Comment: Yes. It is not necessary for basic websites. I wouldn't even recommend it. But if he wants an answer to the question he asked, he will have to face React etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display:none` in the style of the elements you want to wait until the page fully loads. Once its fully load you run a JavaScript to display the elements all at once.

**I personally like using jQuery**

```
$(window).on('load', (e) => {  

    let element_one = $('#element_one_id');
    let element_two = $('#element_two_id');

    // make elements visible

    element_one.css('display','block');
    element_two.css('display','block');

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But what I'm talking about is something completely different. For example, when youtube is opened, the first 500 milliseconds of all video, text etc. are black, it looks like something is being loaded, I mean that.

Comment: I think the links @Shaban gave are exactly related to what I mean.

Comment: Learning React Angular or Vue its not worth it to solve this issue. Those are frameworks that will take you many weeks to learn..

Comment: Yes, I wrote similar code using pure Js as you showed. The time, I'm not sure exactly. Yes, I will have a hard time because I don't have React knowledge for now. But I want to be a Js programmer and I think I should learn React.

Comment: In that case I would suggest Vue.js is way easier to start with than React. Even experience programmers have a hard time learning React.